# Countifs for data starting with a certain number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one data set where only data starting with 5 is correct and rest are incorrect. Hence I am trying to count how many are incorrect with the countif function.

Is it something can I do by `countif(range,"5*")`?

It is not taking these as numbers:

```
56106490
56106490
57130705
57130705
57130705
57130705
57710848
57710848
57839585
57839585
57839585
58137939
58137939
58345877
58345877
58569395
58569395
```

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards only work in `COUNTIF` function when the values are text formatted (not numeric). Try using `SUMPRODUCT` like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(range)="5")+0)`

or assuming all numbers in your range have 8 digits as per your example you could use `COUNTIFS` like this:

`=COUNTIFS(range,">=50000000",range,"<=59999999")`

for large ranges the `COUNTIFS` version is probably faster

Comment: Excellent ! working for this data set