# Countif for Number series (how may)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have bit of problem with the data set where I need to establish the below .

An example of large data set below from where I need to use countifs option where only starts with 1 and 2 are correct and also all the data contains 10 character of numbers .

```
112306766
112306766
201010238
108245234
108245234
120497144
120497144
117372482
117372482
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand your question, try the following solution. In this example the sample data is in B3:B15. In D5 put the following formula and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar to create and Array Formula.

The formula shall now be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula. The sample data is Numbers as Text, it should work even if it's actual number in the cell instead of Text.

```
=SUM(IF(LEFT(IF(LEN(B3:B15)=10,B3:B15),1)="1",1,0),IF(LEFT(IF(LEN(B3:B15)=10,B3:B15),1)="2",1,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my answer to your previous question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1269650/countifs-for-data-starting-with-a-certain-number/1269652#1269652) this just adds an additional complexity but you can essentially do the same, e.g. with `SUMPRODUCT`

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(range)={"1","2"})+0)`

This only works if range is a single column

....or use `COUNTIFS` like this

`=COUNTIFS(range,">=1000000000",range,"<=2999999999")`

Note: for my answer I've assumed 10 digit numbers as the text of your question states - but your example shows 9 digit numbers